# Two options on onchange

Tags: javascript

I have an drop down that is a simple yes/no.

When the user selects "Yes" the page brings a new drop down (New Product) for them to select, when the user selects "No" it should display different drop down (Non Sale Reason)

On my webpage, when the user selects "Yes" it works, but nothing happens when they select "No"

The on change script is:

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: left;"><select name="Retained" id="Retained" onchange="display(this,'Yes','No');" >
```

I have added a code to a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/s0s7dry7/7/

It does not display correctly on here for some reason (nothing hidden but drop downs are hidden on my page)

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't included any Javascript in the JSFiddle - so we can't see what the `display()` method does!

Comment: I'm sorry added it now  http://jsfiddle.net/s0s7dry7/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently passing in three arguments to your `display` function: `this`, `'Yes'` and '`No`'.  The third is not given a name in the function definition, and is effectively ignored; basically, every time you call this function, the `id1` parameter is passed in as `'Yes'`.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but this is probably not doing what you want.  The `txt` variable within the function *will* always be set to whatever the current (i.e. new) value is, but it will always be compared against `id1`; and equally you will only ever modify the document element with ID `'Yes'`.

To fix this you could change the second argument in the `onchange` call to be the newly selected value.  But even this is superfluous, since as noted above you can determine this just from the element reference.  Instead I would remove both the `'Yes'` and the `'No'` parameters, and reduce your `display()` function to just working out what `txt` is.  Now you know what that is, you can tell whether the user selected yes or no, and with a simple if-else you can do whatever you need to do in these separate cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer made me have a think. I changed the javascript to include id2 and now it works

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function display(obj,id1,id2) {
txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
}
if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
}
}
// ]]>
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById("Retained");
el.onchange = function(evt){
    var no = document.getElementById("No");
    var yes = document.getElementById("Yes");
    if(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value === 'No'){console.log("NO")}
    if(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value === 'Yes'){console.log("YES")}
}
```

you can modifiy console.log("No") to no.style.display='block'
you can modifiy console.log("Yes") to yes.style.display='block'

```
  if(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value === 'No'){no.style.display='block'}
  if(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value === 'Yes'){yes.style.display='block'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplified version of your need:

```js
function display(val) {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('options');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById(val).style.display = "block";
    

}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Sale:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <select name="Retained" id="Retained" onchange="display(document.getElementById('Retained').value);">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Yes" style="display: none" class="options">
        <td class="title">New Product:</td>
        <td class="field">
            <select name="RetainedProduct" id="RetainedProduct">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="£10">£10</option>
                <option value="£6.50">£6.50</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="No" style="display: none" class="options">
        <td class="title">Non Sale Reason:</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="field">
            <select name="RetainedProduct" id="RetainedProduct">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Not interested">Not interested</option>
                <option value="Too expensive">Too expensive</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```